# Data filtering code in Pandas taking lot of time to run

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am executing the below code in Python. Its taking some time run. Is there something  i am doing wrong.

Is there a better a way to do the same.

```
y= list(word)
words = y
similar = [[item[0] for item in model.wv.most_similar(word) if item[1] > 0.7] for word in words]
similarity_matrix = pd.DataFrame({'Root_Word': words, 'Similar_Words': similar})
similarity_matrix = similarity_matrix[['Root_Word', 'Similar_Words']]  
similarity_matrix['Unlist_Root']=similarity_matrix['Root_Word'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
similarity_matrix['Unlist_Similar']=similarity_matrix['Similar_Words'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
similarity_matrix=similarity_matrix.drop(['Root_Word','Similar_Words'],1)
similarity_matrix.columns=['Root_Word','Similar_Words']
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? Expected input and output?

Comment: @Tai, I am trying a generate word similarity dictionary  using Word2Vec  functionality. I am trying to store into a dataframe with  2 columns Root Word and Similar  Words. Only The above piece code is taking some time to run

Comment: Edit it in the main text rather than in the comments. Which part is taking longer? Can you try to time them? Please put in more efforts.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to determine what is going on in the following line as there is not enough data provided (I do not know what `model` is):

```
similar = [[item[0] for item in model.wv.most_similar(word) if item[1] > 0.7] for word in words]
```

The second line below does not seem necessary as you create a DataFrame `similarity_matrix` with only two columns:

```
similarity_matrix = pd.DataFrame({'Root_Word': words, 'Similar_Words': similar})
# This below does not do anything
similarity_matrix = similarity_matrix[['Root_Word', 'Similar_Words']]
```

The `apply` method is not very fast. Try using vectorized methods already implemented in pandas as shown below. [Here](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) is a useful link about this topic.

```
similarity_matrix['Unlist_Root'] = similarity_matrix['Root_Word'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
# will be faster like this:
similarity_matrix['Unlist_Root'] = similarity_matrix['Root_Word'].str.join(', ')
```

Similarly:

```
similarity_matrix['Unlist_Similar'] = similarity_matrix['Similar_Words'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
# will be faster like this:
similarity_matrix['Unlist_Similar'] = similarity_matrix['Similar_Words'].str.join(', ')
```

The rest of the code could not run much faster.

If you provided more data/info we could help you more than that...